# My PHP code doesn't receive the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a html form that uses a jquery script to get the data and push to a php file to email it to me.

the jQuery:

```
'use strict';
var isValidElement = function isValidElement(element) {
    return element.name && element.value;
};
var isValidValue = function isValidValue(element) {
    return ![
        'checkbox',
        'radio'
    ].includes(element.type) || element.checked;
};
var isCheckbox = function isCheckbox(element) {
    return element.type === 'checkbox';
};
var isMultiSelect = function isMultiSelect(element) {
    return element.options && element.multiple;
};
var getSelectValues = function getSelectValues(options) {
    return [].reduce.call(options, function (values, option) {
        return option.selected ? values.concat(option.value) : values;
    }, []);
};

var formToJSON = function formToJSON(elements) {
    return [].reduce.call(elements, function (data, element) {
        if (isValidElement(element) && isValidValue(element)) {
            if (isCheckbox(element)) {
                data[element.name] = (data[element.name] || []).concat(element.value);
            } else if (isMultiSelect(element)) {
                data[element.name] = getSelectValues(element);
            } else {
                data[element.name] = element.value;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }, {});
};
var handleFormSubmit = function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = formToJSON(form.elements);
     var request;

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/dev/afelipeor/php/email.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        $('.card').addClass('hide').after(emailSent);
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );

        });
    };
    var form = $('#contact-form')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

And the php:

```
<?php

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $to = "myemail@afelipeor.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $message = $data;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,"This is an automated email from the contact form", "From: system@afelipeor.com\r\n");
?>
```

The jQuery code is running properly, and outputs the expected. However, every time I recieve the email, the message part is empty.

I looked all over the internet and stack overflow, and tried everything I found, but I still wasn't able to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `data` appears to be an object, maybe `$message = var_dump($data);` will work? What does `data` look like in the php script before you try to assign it?

Comment: `$_POST` is a reserved, superglobal variable. Trying to overwrite it is a very bad idea unless you know exactly what you're doing. In any case, have you tried a `var_dump` on your input? Add `var_dump($_POST, file_get_contents('php://input'));` before your first line and see what you get.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` show if you comment out `//$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`?

Comment: @DevishOne and Ed, I tried what you suggested, but had the same results. AbraCadaver, `print_r($_POST)` hasn't been doing anything. I'm new to php, so it might be because I'm doing something wrong